# Form post data from checkboxes lost in Firefox using cakePHP Formhelper

Tags: php, html, firefox, cakephp

I'm developping my first cakePHP application and I encountered my first major problem. I have a Search/Filter form which submits data to the Index action of my controller. This is all done using cakePHP's Formhelper. I then access this data using $this->data. It works fine in chrome and IE, but in Firefox all my fields are empty. According to the post data from Firebug, the HTML is fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tv6k.png

What am I missing?

In my view :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Contact', array('action' => 'index')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('keywords', array('class' => 'search', 'label' => false)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('sex', array('label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'div' => false, 'options' => array('F' => __('Female'),'M' => __('Male')))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('language', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'options' => $languages)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => __('Search'))); ?>
```

In my controller :

```
class ContactsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Paginator');


    public function index(){

        $this->set('languages', $this->Contact->Language->find('list',array('fields' => array('Language.id', 'Language.label_en'))));


        echo pr($this->data);
    }
```

Comment: I think this is server side problem.

Comment: Done, but according to the post data it's fine..

Comment: Clear all caches in all browsers and try again.

Comment: and you don't need to echo a pr();  just use debug($this->data) instead.

Comment: AND - if you're on 2.x +, it should be `$this->request->data`, not `$this->data`

Comment: I tried with $this->request->data but no cigar - same results.

Comment: OK I found the solution. I ditched the Formhelper and coded my checkboxes by hand. Everything works now.

Comment: There's more : It turns out this was caused by my shitty markup. I had planned to put the checkboxes in some <td>s but chose otherwise later. I had still my <table> and <tr> tags wrapped around my inputs which caused the hidden input to be outputed after my checkboxes.